# Rails : Controller without action and without view gives error but Controller without action and with view doesnt

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I generated a controller without an action with command

```
rails g controller tests
```

added the route as `resources :tests`

I try to access the page `{localhost}/tests/new` and get error `The action new could not be found for TestsController` which is correct as i have not included the action.

Now if i include the action i will get a different error as `Template missing` and when i include the required template that error would be resolved and application works fine.

But If instead of including the action i add the required template `new` directly, still my error   `The action new could not be found for TestsController` is resolved even though I have not included an action. How does that work in Rails? The action is not mandatory? How did Rails resolve my error in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've heard the phrase "convention over configuration", and that's what's happening in this case. Remember that all your controllers are inheriting a lot of methods and behavior that you, the Rails developer, need to know about but don't directly see; the most obvious behavior is that, after running the controller method with the same name as the URL action requested, Rails looks for a view page by the same name as that action. (Unless you've explicitly used the *render* command to change this behavior.)

In fact, Rails does the above even if the controller *doesn't have* a matching method. It just shrugs and looks for a view template having the same name.

Here's a rough outline of Rails' logic here:

1. I've received a request for "/tests/new". Do I have a route for that? Let me look in the routes file.
2. I found a matching route, and it points to the controller "test" and the action "new".
3. Do I have a controller with the name "TestController"? Yes, I found one.
4. Does that controller have an action with the name "new"? No, I don't see one, but I guess that's not a problem, I'll just look for the default view.
5. Is there a view at the path "/app/views/test/new"? Yes, I see one, so I'll prepare that template and send it back to the user.

It looks like some other answerers got caught up in pluralization issues, but you should be seeing the behavior you describe even if you fix those issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you did your test by *taking out* the controller action after having added it, then rails could still be caching the route, and rendering the view - perhaps even from a cache.